# How to add headers to this request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, request

I have little experience with requests, so I did not know how to adapt other examples to my specific case

```
const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await ContactUser.find()
        return res.status(200).json({
            data
        })
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(200).json({
            err: "Server error"
        })
    }
};
```

This is my code and I need these headers:

```
new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' })
'Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Range'
// and 
'Content-Range', 'users 0-20/20'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple nothing to much to explain.

`res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});`

the name of the syntax of this method is **writeHead method**